# mysql_data_seek not working

Tags: php, mysql

my code is,

```
$query3     =   "SELECT * FROM db_exam_skip WHERE user='$session'";
$result3        =   mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
$length3        =   mysql_num_rows($result3);
while($rows3    =   mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{
    $query1 =   "SELECT * FROM db_exam_questions WHERE id='$rows3[ques_id]'";
    $result1   =    mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
    $length1   =    mysql_num_rows($result1);
}

if(isset($_POST['next']))
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['list']))
        {
            mysql_data_seek($result1,$_SESSION['list']);
        }
        else
        {
            $list       =   $_POST['list'];
            mysql_data_seek($result1,$list);
        }
    }

<?php
        while($rows1    =   mysql_fetch_row($result1))
        {
            $start  =   $rows1[0];
            $_SESSION['start']  =   $start;
    ?>
 <form action="" method="post">
    <p style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold"><?php echo $rows1[5]; ?></p>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <input type='hidden' name='number' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['order']++; ?>' />
        <input type='hidden' name='list' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['list']++; ?>' />
        <input type='hidden' name='ques_id' value='<?php echo $rows1[0]; ?>' />
        <input type='hidden' name='correct' value='<?php echo $rows1[10]; ?>' />
        <li><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" /> <?php echo $rows1[6]; ?> <br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" /> <?php echo $rows1[7]; ?> <br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" /> <?php echo $rows1[8]; ?> <br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" /> <?php echo $rows1[9]; ?> <br></li>
    </ul>
  <input type="submit" class="button4" value="Next" name="next" />
</form>
    <?php
    break;
        }
    ?>
```

my question is, after the first question is loaded, when i press next button to load the second question I am getting the below error.

`Warning: mysql_data_seek(): Offset 2 is invalid for MySQL result index 8 (or the query data is unbuffered) in C:\wamp\www\Albert\ICAMS\start_skip_question.php on line 15`

I have tried a lot to solve this error. But till now no success. Is there any method to solve. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the result set is `empty`.I think query is returning `empty set`. 
You will get this error if result set is empty
check the [PHP DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

First check if you are getting ant rows from the result

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
}
```